# Understanding the difference between Cursor API and Iterator API of StAX

Tags: java, xml, iterator, cursor, stax

Ok, when learning how to process XML with `StAX` API. I saw that it has 2 ways to get the XML document parsed namely:

Cursor API

Iterator API

The `Cursor API` is where you use `XMLStreamReader` and it's `next()` and `hasNext()` methods.
The `Iterator API` uses `XMLEventReader` in much the same way as above.

The book sums up the `Iterator API` in just a paragraph which is not quite descriptive. It says that you use this when you want to see what event will come up next and based on the value of `XMLEvent`, you can use the `XMLStreamReader` to skip or process the upcoming event.

I am unable to get my head around this. Could someone please explain **HOW?**

### SSCCE for Cursor API

```
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StaxCursorDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("helloWorld.xml"));
            XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(input);

            while(xmlStreamReader.hasNext()){
                int event = xmlStreamReader.next();
                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT){
                    System.out.println("Beginning parsing of document");
                }
                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT){
                    System.out.println("Ending parsing of document");
                }
                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT){
                    System.out.println("NOTE: " + xmlStreamReader.getText());
                }
                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
                    System.out.println("Beginning Element: " + xmlStreamReader.getLocalName());
                    for(int i = 0;i<xmlStreamReader.getAttributeCount();i++){
                        System.out.println("Attribute is: " + xmlStreamReader.getAttributeLocalName(i));
                        System.out.println("Attribute value is: " + xmlStreamReader.getAttributeValue(i));
                    }
                }
                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT){
                    System.out.println("End Element: ");
                }
                if(event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS){
                    System.out.println("Value: " + xmlStreamReader.getText());
                }
            }
        }catch(FactoryConfigurationError e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch(XMLStreamException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is more to it, but [`XMLEventReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) delivers [`XMLEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html)-Objects that give you a little more flexibility and functionality whereas [`XMLStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) does not create these Objects for you.

Therefore, [`XMLStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) is performing better while [`XMLEventReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) gives you some more functionality out of the box.